# MS sql server 2012 database to 2008 MS sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to know if there is any way i can restore a 2012 MS sql server database into MS sql server 2008 thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried something? The question is a bit broad and requires additional details. You can probably export the data and then import it into the older version. But if you have used features specific to the new version then you may very well loose some things. Please revise the question and add details.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, not using backup and restore like I'm guessing you'd prefer, however a few other options are discussed here if you are feeling adventurous:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20588/restore-sql-server-2012-backup-to-a-sql-server-2008-database

Sorry not to have happier news!